# Security Dialogflow fulfillment

Tags: http, security, request, basic-authentication, dialogflow-es

I wrote a simple HTTPS server for my Dialogflow bot. In my code I just trust the `req` object like this:

Express routing:

```
app.post('/', Route);
```

The function that Express calls:

```
function Route(req, res) {
    if (req.body.status.errorType !== "success") {
        return ;
    }
    // do something really awesome here
}
```

I think it's not a good idea. I should check the origin of the request. What do you think? Maybe I should use a basic-auth module or something, but I have no idea how to ensure the `req` object has been processed by Dialogflow. How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the answer of my own question. Dialogflow let us define some authentication variable explained at the top of this documentation page:
https://dialogflow.com/docs/fulfillment

so just explore the req.headers.authorization you will find an authentication variable as HTTP protocol describe it :
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication

(concat these three things:

1. Your dialogflow username
2. The character ':'
3. Your dialogflow password

and encode it in base64)

Pretty awesome !