# Security Dialogflow fulfillment request headers

Tags: python, basic-authentication, dialogflow-es

This is a follow up on [Security Dialogflow fulfillment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48113948/security-dialogflow-fulfillment) thread.

the answer there

> explore the req.headers.authorization you will find an authentication variable
>
> (concat these three things:
>   Your dialogflow username
>
> The character ':'
>
> Your dialogflow password
>
> and encode it in base64)

makes sense but in my python implementation the
request headers I get is:

```
Accept: */*
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 571
Host: xxxxxxxx
User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.5.4 (Java/1.8.0_151)
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
X-Forwarded-Proto: https
X-Forwarded-For: xx.xxxx.xx..xx
PS: I tried both V1 and V2
```

not sure how to take care of authorization

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to set the basic auth fields in the Fullfilment settings (the ones below the Fullfilment-URL). Only then you will receive the base64 encoded part in the `Authorization` Header.

This has nothing to do with your personal credentials you use to login to dialogflow! **Do not use them for basic auth!**